# Configuring Cassandra's TokenAware and LatencyAware policy together in C++ driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After reading about the different load balancing policies available(https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/configuration/), it seems to me that for best performance,particularly in multi data-center cluster, token-aware and latency-aware policy should be used together('Performance Tips' section of the above mentioned article).

As per my understanding(assuming replication factor > 1), when we'll use both of these policies together, then the client will calculate the hash of the primary key used in the query and then based on the latency, it will chose the best replica for execution of that query. Is this understanding correct in the given scenario?

Also, I wanted to understand how exactly to implement/configure these 2 policies together. Do I need to just simply enable both policies one after the other in my C++ code? If not, can someone share the code snippet for enabling both the policies together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct - you can use both policies together. To enable them - just call 2 corresponding functions together, and set necessary settings as described in documentation.

If you have several DCs then it makes sense also enable DC-aware load balancing...

Comment: If I enable DC aware load balancing as well, which means, I'll be using 3 load balancing policies ; does the order in which I enable these policies matter? I mean, in the code, out of the 3 policies, should I first enable a particular policy and then some other, like that?

Comment: You can enable them in any order - they are setup when you establish connection. I see in the source code that DC-aware & token-aware policies are enabled by default (it's default for all drivers). Each policy wrap another in following order - start with `DCAwarePolicy`, that is wrapped by `TokenAwarePolicy`, and then wrapped by `LatencyAwarePolicy` if it's enabled. See https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/src/config.hpp#L90 for full list of policies.